# Cannot insert object into vector of same type

Tags: c++, vector, types, stl

So I'm pretty new to c++:

I have a class XMLItem.

I create an instance of the class XMLItem by

```
XMLItem the_item = XMLItem(params...);
```

I create a vector to hold XMLItems by

```
vector<XMLItem> my_vect;
```

However when I try to insert the_item into my_vect with

```
my_vect.insert(the_item);
```

I get the following output error:

```
error: no matching function for call ‘std::vector<XMLItem>::insert(XMLItem&)’
```

It looks like the compiler is complaining that I'm trying to insert a reference to an object of type XMLItem but I have no idea why that would be the case. Is there something I'm misunderstanding about initializing objects in c++?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Answer (score 1):

[***std::vector::insert()***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) inserts elements at the specified location in the container. You need to specify position. There is no any overload of `insert()` which takes one argument that's why compiler gives you an error. You should use `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` if you don't want to specify position.

Answer (score 1):

`insert` operation requires a position. If position doesn't matter to your case then you can use `emplace_back` (C++11) or `push_back`.